# Navigation in phonegap application fails when I use GET variables

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

I've created a small 2 page application, but it fails when I navigate to a page using GET variables, like

```
window.location.href = 'game.html?id=2'
```

Navigating by using `www/game.html` works great, but breaks the logic. Could anyone tell me why this is?

The above `window.location.href` throws

```
CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed :: www/game.html?id=2
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a PhoneGap/Cordova app and it occurs only in windows phone 8? Anyone a hint?

Comment: Damn, same issue here...

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code it has to work.

```
var dirPath = location.href.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '');
window.location = dirPath +"/game.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace '?' symbol with # I tested, it works fine

**Detailed:**

**Original code**
window.location.href = 'game.html?id=2'

**Replace as**
window.location.href = 'game.html#id=2'

Jquery for windows phone doesn't  support '?' symbol