# Phonegap app works on emulator not on device

Tags: ajax, cordova, emulation, simulator

I`m testing simple phonegap app for adding comment with remote server. i`ve tested in telerik icenium simulator and in browser and it works. But when I try to test in visual studio emulator and click the button it says "CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed :: www/index.html?email=fgg@vv.com&comment=Gjjj". I`ve tested on device too, but there nothing happens.

Here is the code.
index.html - the main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">

    <title>jQuery form post</title>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/post.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onBodyLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        label, b {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    //<a href="http://bgg.comxa.com/new.php">content</a>
    <div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
        <form>
            <label for="email">
                <b>Email</b>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            </label>

            <label for="comment">
                <b>Comment</b>
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

post.js

```
$(document).bind('deviceready', function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var landmarkID = $(this).parent().attr('data-landmark-id');
            var postData = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData + '&lid=' + landmarkID,
                //change the url for your project
                url: "http://bgg.comxa.com/new.php",
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this error message does not state that there is anything wrong with your index.html file, it does not seem to be able to reach it at all.

Check out this thread: [Navigation in phonegap application fails when I use GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601099/navigation-in-phonegap-application-fails-when-i-use-get-variables)

There might be something about the way you try to reach your index.html file. Maybe you are going straight to "index.html" and not "www/index.html", as it states in the post answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that is not the problem, because app works fine in one simulator of telerik app builder.

Comment: Hm, okay, have you checked that something successfully runs on Visual Studio with cordova? If not I would try to put this app aside and just get it working first :-)

Try this url f.ex.: http://stuarthallows.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/setting-up-for-phonegapcordova-development-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading, i think the problem is in webkit prowsers. I`ve read that there is issues with ajax requests in webkit based browsers. I will try the code at real mobile phone device and see...